# Interface and class in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, class, interface

i was having a model class: of structure:

```
    export default class Info {
      empId: number;
      name: string;
      designation: string
      constructor(data) {
        this.empId = data.empId;
        this.name = data.name;
        this.designation = data.designation;
      } 
}
```

I have to change this class to an interface.

```
export default interface Info{
empId: number;
  name: string;
  designation: string
}
```

service class:

```
     getInfo(): Promise<Array<Info>> {  
             return http
             .get(this.ENDPOINTS.PRODUCTS, {
             })
             .then((response) => {
               console.log("response", response)
               return response.data.map((info) => new Info(info));
               )
             })
             .catch((error) => {
               throw error;
             });
           }
```

I am getting error in this line **return response.data.map((info) => new Info(info));** stating `'Info' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` Can anyone help me with how to deal with the interface here and what will be the syntax. Can please anyone help me in understanding when to use Class and Interface in React app

Comment: you converted your class to interface but with `new Info(..)` you are still using it as if it's a class. what happens if you just return `response.data` without mapping?

Comment: That works,but i am confused when to use interface/class as a model in reactjs app

Comment: you should probably go through [some tutorials for React + Typescript](https://alligator.io/react/typescript-with-react/#class-components) (or any other)